# No tension force counterbalances the horizontal force in this problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, torque

[image: castle]
This is my problem. I tried solving it, however I thought I had to add a tension, in the rope, but apparently in the solutions there's no mention to it! But shouldn't there be a tension in the rope? Or at least some kind of resistance from the wall! Because otherwise there's the horizontal component of the force $F$ that is just not balanced, so the wall would just break!

Here's the solutions, with no mention of tension force!
[image: solcas]

Which approach is correct? Consider that this is an exam question for a Applied Mathematics course of the second year of university!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a horizontal force and a vertical force exerted on the drawbridge by the wall, but they are not shown in the diagram.   Therefore the diagram is incomplete and incorrect.    The missing horizontal force is equal in magnitude and opposite in direction to the horizontal component of the chain's tension force, $F cos\theta$.  The vertical force would be $\frac1{2} mg$ upward.